# Expected value over joint probability measure

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, optimization, stochastic-processes

I would like to maximise an expected value of a function $g(x_1,\xi_1,...,x_N,\xi_N)$, that depends on several random variables $\xi_1, \xi_2,...,\xi_N$ and corresponding decision variables $x_1,...,x_N$. The random variables might be dependent on each other and I know the joint probability distribution $F(x_1,...,x_N)=\mathbb{P}(\xi_1\leq x_1,...,\xi_N\leq x_N)$.
The function $g(x_1,\xi_1,...,x_N,\xi_N)$ is constructed in such a way, that one can split it into N functions in the following way:

### $g(x_1,\xi_1,...,x_N,\xi_N)=g_1(x_1,\xi_1)+g_2(x_2,\xi_2)+...+g_N(x_N,\xi_N)$

What I do not understand is, how to split the expected value of this function into N expected values, if the initial expectation was over joint measure?

$\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}(g(x_1,\xi_1,...,x_N,\xi_N))=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}(g_1(x_1,\xi_1)+g_2(x_2,\xi_2)+...+g_N(x_N,\xi_N))=?$

Will the resulting sum of expectations be over marginal distributions of $\xi_i$ each or conditional distributions will be involved? If conditional distributions are involved, then how?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Expected sum = sum of expectations. To compute the latter, use marginal distributions.

Comment: The expectation can be clearly splited in the following N expectations according to the linearity of the expectation: $\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}(g_i(x_i, \xi_i))=\int...\int g_i(x_i, y_i)f(y_i)f(y_1,...,y_{i-1}, y_{i+1},...,y_N|y_i)dy_1 dy_2... dy_N$. f(y_i) is the marginal. But there is still the conditional density $f(y_1,...,y_{i-1}, y_{i+1},...,y_N|y_i)$ - I do not really see how to get rid of it, if the variables are dependent? So, I understand that the sum of expectations is the expectation of the sum, but why can we use marginals?

Comment: Forget about the conditional density. $\mathbb{E}(g(\xi)) = \int g(x) f_\xi(x)dx$. Always. In other words, to compute expectation of a (function of) single random variable you need *only* its distribution.

Comment: Thanks! I think, I understood why - the integral over this density is 1, so it does not influence the result)